# Regex capture optional groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm trying capture 2 groups of numbers, where each group is optional and should only be captured if contains numbers. Here is a list of all valid combinations that it supposed to match:

1. `123(456)`
2. `123`
3. `(456)`
4. `abc(456)`
5. `123(efg)`

And these are not valid combinations and should **not** be matched:

6. `abc(efg)`
7. `abc`
8. `(efg)`

However, my regex fails on `#4` and `#5` combinations even though they contain numbers.

```js
const list = ["123(456)", "123", "(456)", "abc(456)", "123(def)", "abc(def)", "abc", "(def)"];
const regex = /^(?:(\d+))?(?:\((\d+)\))?$/;

list.map((a,i) => console.log(i+1+". ", a + "=>".padStart(11-a.length," "), JSON.stringify((a.match(regex)||[]).slice(1))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important;}
```

So, the question is why when used `?` behind a group, it doesn't "skip" that group if nothing matched?

P.S.
With this regex it also captures `#4`, but not `#5`: `/(?:^|(\d+)?)(?:\((\d+)\))?$/`

Comment: Maybe `/^\d+\b|\(\d+\)$/` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/702oMF/1).

Answer (score 2):

Here an idea without global flag and supposed to only match the needed items:

```
^(?=\D*\d)(\d+)?\D*(?:\((\d*)\))?\D*$
```

- `^(?=\D*\d)` The [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at `^` [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) checks for at least a [digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `(\d+)?` [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the digits to the [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) *first group*
- `\D*` followed by any amount of *non digits*
- `(?:\((\d*)\))?` digits in parentheses to optional *second group*
- `\D*$` matching any amount of `\D` *non digits* up to the `$` end

[See your JS demo](https://tio.run/##TY5Na8MwDIbv@RXC7CA1qYv3UcpCmstOO2yHHusONMdNPbwkJKZs0P@eORmU6iC9r4Qe6YvPPJjedWF53oyjaZshgHcxFbAX6v4BH5/WJDKY9FSunj/N7Qwre7z2b/S8M/tDnvzje1vbn8hffWBZ6JeFrgh1lVIZNZbPGqNbkKa5cbfKk2R6SH5zh8iZIyi2MJFab6Vva3SpSoWEeIkhBVFshey42gXuAyq1ZOltU4dTJkBQBq@79zc5hN41tTv@RmIEB3PC@Su6XPYHkoN3xqKiGPk4/gE) or a [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mV38Oo/1) (the `[^\d\n]` only for multiline demo)

Comment: Your explanation is very good. But I don't get where the _optional_ is represented in that regex. What makes the second group _optional_?

Comment: @buhtz The second group is contained inside an *optional* [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). This part of pattern: `(?:optional non capturing group\((second group)\))?`

Answer (score 1):

A solution to what you're looking for can be done with lookahead, see:

```
(?=^\d+(?:\(|$))(\d+)|(?=\d+\)$)(\d+)
```

Rough translation: a number from the start ending with a bracket (or end of line) OR a number in brackets somewhere in the text

**To answer question on optional captured groups**

Yes, if a group is marked optional e.g. `(A*)?` it does make the whole group optional.
In your case, it is simply a case of the regex not matching - even if the optional part isn't there (verify with the help of a regex debugger)

Comment: Thank you, but that regex fails on `#1`, it only captures first group.

Comment: it captures both https://regex101.com/r/4oTfpO/1

Comment: Oh, yes, with global flag. This makes it complicated though, because it requires additional "loop" to go through all matches.

Comment: so for 123(456) is the output you're looking for 123456? @vanowm

Comment: take a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/y71dRf/1 for 123(456) it'll match 123(456 while keeping all other cases as usual, you'll have to deal with the bracket with either another regex sub/appropriate string function, hope this helps

Comment: yes, as 2 different numbers, if you look at the snippet, it returns an array with 2 elements, one of which could be a `null`/`undefined`

Answer (score 1):

@WiktorStribiżew and @akash had good ideas, but they are based on global flag, which requires additional loop to gather all the matches.

For now, I come up with this regex, which matches anything, but it captures only what I need.

```js
const list = ["123(456)", "123", "(456)", "abc(456)", "123(def)", "abc(def)", "abc", "(def)"];
const regex = /(?:(\d+)|^|[^(]+)+?(?:\((?:(\d+)|\D*)\)|$)+?/;

list.map((a,i) => console.log(i+1+". ", a + "=>".padStart(11-a.length," "), JSON.stringify((a.match(regex)||[]).slice(1))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important;}
```